# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: for libTYCommonLib.a

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/CNS/Downloads/Demo Source Code 2/iOS/TYCommonLic_Demo/TYCommonLic_Demo/libTYCommonLib.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/CNS/Downloads/Demo Source Code 2/iOS/TYCommonLic_Demo/TYCommonLic_Demo/libTYCommonLib.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SalesSlipModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TYSwiperController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

getting this error. please help how to resolve it?

Comment: show your code from ViewController.m  for better understanding.

Comment: actually this code is 2-3 years old and I am trying to run in xcode 8.2 ..this library is not compatible with new xcode

Comment: are you tried in device

Comment: i tried 6s but getting error that "requires the “armv64” capability which is not supported by iPhone"

Comment: Re-build `libTYCommonLib.a` for simulator (`x86_64`) and `arm64` (see `Valid Architectures` in build settings of `libTYCommonLib`).

Answer (score 1):

**You need to link m file** :

Finally found the answer. In your target settings, locate build phases and navigate to compile sources. Once there just ad the .m file that is getting the error to the list.

Comment: can you give another solution?